# Invariant Violation error Object are not valid as a React Child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to render a Segment, which will render a Photos or Reviews component, depending on which is selected. The renderSegments function is working and the console.log('Rendered Photos') is working. The issue seems to be how I'm returning the Photos component.

The Photos component should just be rendering the text "Photos" to the screen in the ScrollView of the View.js screen.

**Error:**

> Error: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid
>   as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}). If
>   you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

**Photos.js**

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Dimensions, View, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';

// Screen Dimensions
const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

// Component: Photos
export default class Photos extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.photos}>Photos</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

// Styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: width,
  },
  photos: {
    fontFamily: 'System',
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '700',
    color: '#000',
  },
});
```

**View.js**

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Dimensions, SafeAreaView, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Left, Body, Right, Button, Icon, Title, Segment, Content } from 'native-base';

// Imports: Components
import Photos from '../components/Photos';
import Reviews from '../components/Reviews';

// Screen Dimensions
const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

// Screen: View
export default class View extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      segmentSelected: 'Photos',
    };
  }

  // React Navigation: Options
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerStyle: {
      elevation: 0,
      shadowOpacity: 0,
      borderBottomWidth: 0,
    },
  };

  // Render Segments (Photos/Reviews)
  renderSegments = async () => {
    try {
      console.log('Rendering Segments');

      if (this.state.segmentSelected === 'Photos') {
        console.log('Rendered Photos');
        return (
          <Photos />
        )
      }
      if (this.state.segmentSelected === 'Reviews') {
        console.log('Rendered Reviews');
        return (
          <Reviews />
        )
      }
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.segmentContainer}>
          <Segment style={{ width: width }} style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
            <Button
              first
              active={this.state.segmentSelected === 'Photos' ? true : false}
              onPress={() => this.setState({ segmentSelected: 'Photos' })}
            >
              <Text style={{ color: this.state.segmentSelected === 'Photos' ? '#fff' : '#007AFF'}}>               Photos              </Text>
            </Button>
            <Button
              last
              active={this.state.segmentSelected === 'Reviews' ? true : false}
              onPress={() => this.setState({ segmentSelected: 'Reviews' })}
            >
              <Text style={{ color: this.state.segmentSelected === 'Reviews' ? '#fff' : '#007AFF'}}>              Reviews              </Text>
            </Button>
          </Segment>
        </View>

        <ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
          <View>
            {this.renderSegments()}
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}

// Styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    // justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: width,
  },
  segmentContainer: {
    marginTop: 7,
    marginBottom: 7,
    borderColor: '#999999',
    width: width,
    borderBottomWidth: .2,
  },
  text: {
    fontFamily: 'System',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: '#222222',
  },
});
```

Comment: Since `renderSegments` is `async` function, it returns a Promise object (which React does not know how to render), not a React component directly. [detailed explanation in Google developer docs](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions#async_return_values). `renderSegments` only produces a React component when the Promise that it returns fulfills. Does `renderSegments` need to be async?

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know leaving async on the function and not using await would make a difference, but it now renders.